# How does one determine which columns to set as an index in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame of financial securities, which often have multiple identifiers:

[image]

Should I choose only one column to set as the index? Should I set all potential identifiers as the index? Should I set all text data as an index, and leave all numeric data as columns? What is the best practice?

Comment: In my opinion generally  the best is default monotonic index (`0,1,2,3,...`), but it depends what do you need exactly. Also better is unique index as duplicates.

Comment: drop duplicates and then use default monotonic index

Comment: This is totally dependent on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In this example, all identifiers are already unique. There are no duplicates in any of the text columns in this table.

Comment: It's generally a little bit more efficient to have an integer index if you intend to sort, join or filter later on. You can try this comparison. https://gist.github.com/prashnts/e61b49bcc424fb042677eb1eff3edf51

Answer (score 0):

This is more about database design than pandas.

The decision should be based on the business meaning of the dataframe (table in relational database) and its columns. E.g., if 'Internal Security ID' is used to identify this kind of data in its business, then it should be set as the index.

However, if you are not sure, just stick with the default integer index.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to stick with the default index unless you have a need to have one of your columns as an index. If you do, I strongly recommend using a column with unique values. If there exists duplicates, this will cause you a lot of headache.